# Change Bootstrap's mobile navbar breakpoint

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm sorry if the title is confusing, the actual problem is very simple to understand.

I have a bootstrap responsive navbar which toggles between mobile and desktop view at 768px breakpoint.

However, I would like it to keep the mobile navbar til 992px breakpoint.

Because above 768px wide, this is how the menu looks

[image]

So I added a media query to the css to fix that

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Now the mobile menu toggles at 992px but the sub-menus are not displaying in their correct position above 768px and below 992px

[image]

How can I fix that?

And am I doing the media queries correctly?

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/8zne82d2/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also target `.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu`

Try to add something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

Example here https://jsfiddle.net/8zne82d2/9/

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.